# The Poisson equation with $L^2$ data has a unique weak solution in $H^1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, poissons-equation, elliptic-equations

In picture below, I have proved that if $f\in L^2(U)$ , (*)  has unique weak solution. I use the Lax Milgran to prove it. I think some conditions are  redundant.

> [image]

Comment: I edited the title to make it more informative. But I couldn't do the same with the question, because my attempt to read your mind was unsuccessful. What conditions do you think are redundant, and why?

Comment: @Normal  I think the last one and last second equations are not needed. Because this Neumann's problem always has weak solution. Only need $f\in L^2(U)$

Comment: If you drop $\partial u/\partial \nu=0$... what is the "Neumann problem"  here? Besides, this condition is a part of (*); if your function $u$ does not satisfy it, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Normal I mean $\int_UDu\cdot Dv dx=...$ and $\int_U f dx=0$.  Not any of  (*)

Comment: Also, the second to last equation is part of the _definition_ of a weak solution to $(*)$.

Comment: P.S., I know the solution to this problem has been previously posted on MSE, but I can't seem to find it right now.

Comment: @charlestoncrabb found and linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no redundant conditions here.

1. The equation $\int_U Du\cdot Dv = \int_U fv$ is not a new condition: it is the *definition* of what it means for $u$ to be a weak solution of $-\Delta u = f$. In other words, it replaces $-\Delta u=f$, which does not hold literally since $u$ need not be twice differentiable.
2. If $\int_U f\ne 0$, then there is no solution. Just put $v\equiv 1$ in the definition of the weak solution, above, and $0=\int_U f$ follows.

By the way, the weak solution is not unique. There are infinitely many, since  one can add a constant without affecting the Neumann condition.

And if you are interested in the actual solution, see [Weak solutions to the Neumann's problem (Evans PDE)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/753086)