# Evans Chapter 6 number 4

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider following problem from Evans

> Assume $\Omega$ is connected. A function $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ is a weak solution of
> $$(1)\quad\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
> -\Delta u(x)=f & x\in\Omega\\
> \frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial n}=0 & x\in\partial\Omega\end{array}\right.$$
> if for all $v\in H^1(\Omega)$ there holds
> $$\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\nabla v\,dx=\int_\Omega fv\,dx \,.$$
> Suppose that $f\in L^2(\Omega)$. Prove $(1)$ has a weak solution if and only if
> $$\int_\Omega f\,dx=0.$$

It is quite difficult. Do I need to use Lax Milgram. How would I go about problem?

Comment: There is a mistake: it should be $\nabla u \cdot \nabla v$ instead of $\nabla u \cdot \nabla u$

Comment: It already has an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753086/weak-solutions-to-the-neumanns-problem-evans-pde?rq=1

Comment: ok I'll look at. If I have any questions should I ask it here?